# Is it possible to deliver additional parameters with httpify?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, httpify

I have this code block :

```
login(email, password, deviceToken, callback) {
  httpify({
    url: loginUrl,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Basic ${btoa(`${email}:${password}`)}`
    }
  }, (err, res) => {
    callback(err, res);
  });
}
```

I'd like to also send `deviceToken` to be available as a parameter in the request. It could also appear in the Headers. Either or, it just needs to be delivered.

I'm unfamiliar with `httpify`, and can't seem to find any documentation on it. Would anyone know how to include additional params in an HTTPify request?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to include another header for `deviceToken`:

```
headers: {
  "Authorization": `Basic ${btoa(`${email}:${password}`)}`,
  deviceToken: 'value'
}
```

`httpify` documentation [says](https://github.com/scottcorgan/httpify):

> See the documentation for [`xhr`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xhr) and [`request`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) for a complete list of
>   options.

So if you need to pass the data as a form, refer to request documentation to [post form data](https://github.com/request/request#forms):

```
request.post(loginUrl, {form:{deviceToken:'value'}})
// or
request.post(loginUrl).form({deviceToken:'value'})
// or
request.post({url: loginUrl, form: {deviceToken:'value'}}, function(err, httpResponse, body){ /* ... */ })
```